# Standardizing attr('href') returns in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a link `<a href='?action=run'>`, on a webpage wwww.example.com/foo.html

In Firefox, `attr('href')` returns '?action=run'

In IE, it returns 'http://www.example.com/foo.html?action=run'

1. When using attr('href'), usually which behaviour is expected (are there any standards?)
2. Is it possible to make IE returns just '?action=run' too?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery *should* be handling this for you already, [you can see it in the source here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L336), and [in a quick test here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/64yVu/).

jQuery normalizes it if the browser doesn't already, checked via [`$.support.hrefNormalized`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) (false in IE), it does this for [`href`, `src` and `style` attributes](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L6).

Is it possible you're using a very old version of jQuery that didn't do this?  If so upgrading is your answer.  Also be sure that you are indeed using `.attr('href')` to get the normalization, and not `.href` directly.

Comment: I am using jQUery 1.4.2 and I am quite sure that I am using attr('href'). Will do a quick check back @ work again.