# HREF being modified beyond my control...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm not sure if this is a jquery, javascript or simply a quirk in the browser but consider this code:

```
for(rowIdx=0;rowIdx<theResultSet.rows.length;rowIdx++) {
  thisLine = $("#TestTemplateLI").clone().attr({'id':'test_'+rowIdx}).appendTo("#test_exerciseListUL");
  thisLine.find('[href*="#pageExercise_EXERCISENUMBER"]').each( function(i) {this.href = this.href.replace('EXERCISENUMBER', rowIdx)} );
}
```

The goal of the code above is to clone a list item (`<LI>`, embedded below) HTML fragment, modify it to address an anchor elsewhere on the page and then insert it into an unordered list (`<UL>`).  All that works using the wonders of jquery.  The problem is that once it's been modified, the anchor doesn't seem to work.  Moreover after I mod the HREF programattically, it returns a **full** URL, not just an anchor reference.  Example:

```
<UL id='testTemplate' style="display:none"> 
    <LI class='arrow' id='testTemplateLI'>
        <a href='#pageExercise_EXERCISENUMBER'>  <!-- THIS is the beast in question -->
            <DIV class='LABELCLASS test_labelContainer'>
                <TABLE height=100% width=100%>
                    <TR valign='center'><TD align='center'>EXERCISELABEL</TD></TR>
                </TABLE>
            </DIV>
            <IMG id='test_checkmark_EXERCISENUMBER' class='test_checkMark_off' src="assets/checkmark.png" width=60px height=54px>
            <DIV id='test_item_EXERCISENUMBER' class='test_exNameContainer'>
                <TABLE height=100% width=100%>
                    <TR valign='center'><TD>EXERCISENAME</TD></TR>
                </TABLE>
            </DIV>
        </a>
    </LI>
</UL>
```

So, two things are happening.  One, the modified anchor is simply not working and two, what should modify from "**href='#pageExercise_EXERCISENUMBER'**" to "**href='#pageExercise_0'**" (or whatever the current row index ('rowIdx') is modifies it to: "**href='http://www.mydomain.com/themainpage.php#pageExercise_0'**".

I need a way to tell javascript to stop "helping" me on the href.  As for issue #1, I think it's related to #2.

Thanks in advance,

Scott.

Comment: bind a click function and then use the `window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');` see how that works :)

Comment: u might have to use live, as li is dynamic, n also u might need to use e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.href
```

Will return the fully-qualified URL that the anchor points to.

You can use jQuery's `attr` function to return what you want:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.attr("href", $this.attr("href").replace('EXERCISENUMBER', rowIdx));
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779447/standardizing-attrhref-returns-in-jquery)'s a good post explaining how `.attr("href")` is "normalized"

Comment: Wow.  The UI here needs a bit more help.